# Compile a class in a Vaadin widgetset

Tags: java, vaadin, extend, connector

I tried to follow this tutorial to extend one of my component : https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/2656782

I created both classes `ResetButtonForTextField` and `ResetButtonForTextFieldConnector` that I put in `com.myproject.widgetset.extendedComponents` in `src/main/java` in my WidgetSet project.

After compilation (the widgetset is also compiled) and adding in my code :

`TextField tf = new TextField();`

`ResetButtonForTextField.extend(tf);`

It seems like the extend is not working because I put heaps of logs in the `ResetButtonForTextFieldConnector` class and nothing is displayed in my app logs when I'm using the textfield. I think it's cause of the `ResetButtonForTextFieldConnector` isn't compiled when the widgetset is compiling because I saw that at the end of the tutorial :
"An extension connector needs to be included in a widget set. The class must therefore be defined under the client package of a widget set, just like with component connectors."

So I probably forgot something or maybe I'm doing something wrong that's why I'm asking for help here because I'm stuck !

If anybody could help or advice me  :)
Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Did you specify your own widgetset, so it recompiles including your class? In the widgetcompilation process it displays all founds widgets, yours must be in there too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a gotcha, but you're on the right track. The client-side stuff actually needs to be under a package called `client`. So you could use for example `com.myproject.widgetset.extendedComponents` for server side and gwt.xml and `com.myproject.widgetset.extendedComponents.client` for client-side stuff.